# Summing elements of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix from which I want to sum the elements without including the diagonals. Suppose,

```
 matrixDat <- matrix(1:25, ncol=5)
 colnames(matrixDat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
  rownames(matrixDat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

The result i expect is:

```
c(2+6, 3+11, 4+16, 5+21, 8+12, 9+17, 10+22, 14+18, 15+23, 20+24)
```

ie. summing up 1st row and 1st column without 1. Once it is completed, remove the first row and first column, start with second row and second column, then remove it, do the process with third row, third column, until it reach fifth row, fith column.

Comment: Okay. It's easiest to do this with a loop. Show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
     indx <- lower.tri(matrixDat)
     matrixDat[indx]+t(matrixDat)[indx]
     #[1]  8 14 20 26 20 26 32 32 38 44
```

Or, you could do a loop

```
    vec1 <- vector()
    for(i in 1:ncol(m1)){
    vec1 <- c(vec1,matrixDat[,i][-(1:i)]+matrixDat[i,][-(1:i)])
     }

     unname(vec1)
     #[1]  8 14 20 26 20 26 32 32 38 44
```